# jedi fails to correctly autocomplete from package with the same name as the module that I'm in

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, jedi, emacs-jedi

I'm using emacs and I have configured jedi.el so it autocompletes after dot.
Let's assume that I'm writing a module `my_app.my_module` and I have package installed in env called `my_module`.
My file `my_app/my_module.py` will look like:

```
import my_module

class SomeClass:
    pass
(...)
my_module.<here_i_expect_autocompletion_from_my_module_package>
```

Now the thing is that jedi.el tries to autocomplete from `my_app.my_module`(giving me `SomeClass`etc.) not from `my_module` package installed in env.
What should I do to get expected autocompletion?

**Edit**: Looks like this is an `jedi` issue not `jedi.el`, because i can reproduce issue using only `jedi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a problem of `jedi`, not of `jedi.el`.
Furthermore it seems that this behavior is specific for  projects based on `pyramid` framework.